# как удалить элемент из множества

Tags: python

есть множество a

```
b = [3,4,5]
a = set(b)
```

когда пытаюсь найти множество равное этому но без какого-то элемента так:

```
    с = a.remove(3)
    c = None
```

почему так,и как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `remove` удаляет элемент из множества, а не возвращает множество без удаляемого элемента

```
b = [3,4,5]
a = set(b)
a.remove(3)
a
set([4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

`.pop(i)` удаляет i-ый элемент и возвращает его. Если индекс не указан, удаляется последний элемент

```
b = [3, 4, 5]
b.pop(0)
>>>[4, 5]
```